# Laravel Update Multiple Columns with QueryBuilder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm using Query builder, I successfully update na first column but on the second query the change doesnt happen, I already checked the view part the name of input and its correct. here is my code.

```
  DB::table('area')
        ->where('id', $request->get('area_id'))
        ->update(['island_group_id' => $request->get('island_group_id')],
                 ['region_id'       => $request->get('region_id')]);
        return 'test';
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use Fluent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$updateDetails = [
    'island_group_id' => $request->get('island_group_id'),
    'region_id' => $request->get('region_id')
];

DB::table('area')
    ->where('id', $request->get('area_id'))
    ->update($updateDetails);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
DB::table('area')
    ->where('id', $request->get('area_id'))
    ->update([
             'island_group_id' => $request->get('island_group_id'),
             'region_id'       => $request->get('region_id')
            ]);
    return 'test';
```

Answer (score 5):

I think it will be helpful to you.

```
$area_id = $request->get('area_id');
$island_group_id = $request->get('island_group_id'); 
$region_id = $request->get('region_id');

$update_details = array(
    'island_group_id' => $island_group_id
    'region_id'       => $region_id
);

DB::table('area')
    ->where('id', $area_id)
    ->update($update_details);
```

Comment: Ohh nice approach there bro

Comment: Thank you. Its very pleasant to me.

Answer (score 3):

Because you use every time new array for update field. Please use one array for update multiple field like:

```
DB::table('area')
        ->where('id', $request->get('area_id'))
        ->update(array(
                  'island_group_id'=>$request->get('island_group_id'),
                  'region_id'=>$request->get('region_id')
         ));
```